# How to print the value of a single cell using MySQL and PHP?

Tags: php, mysql

This returns a blank page:

```
<?php

$con=mysqli_connect("xxx.x.xx.x","user","password","db");

// check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
  {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }

$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT column FROM table WHERE id=1");

print $result;

mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

And this returns data:

```
<?php

$con=mysqli_connect("xxx.x.xx.x","user","password","db");

// check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
  {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }

$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM table");

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
  {
  echo $row['column_1'] . " " . $row['column_2'];
  echo "<br>";
  }

mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

What is wrong with the first block of code that prevents it returning any data?

Comment: A `mysqli_query` result can't be printed out, the data needs to be fetched. See the manual for examples http://us3.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php

Comment: Try the following: `$row = mysqli_fetch_array(mysqli_query($con, "SELECT column FROM table WHERE id=1"));`
And output using: `echo $row['column'];`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php

tells me that `mysqli_query` returns a `mysqli_query` object. Not a primitive value like string or int.

The exact line that says this is:

> Returns FALSE on failure. For successful SELECT, SHOW, DESCRIBE or
>   EXPLAIN queries mysqli_query() will return a mysqli_result object. For
>   other successful queries mysqli_query() will return TRUE.

Hence the first block does not work because the first block assumes the value in the `column` is automatically returned.

In fact, if you used the same `SELECT column from table where id=1`, you still have to use the while loop to extract the values because it is STILL a mysqli_result object you are getting back.

By while loop I mean this:

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
  echo $row['column_1'];
  echo "<br>";
}
```

I hope this answers your question.